# How do I iterate over an Array field reflectively?

Tags: java, reflection, arrays

I have

```
Class<? extends Object> class1 = obj.getClass();
    Field[] fields = class1.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field aField : fields) {
      aField.setAccessible(true);
       if (aField.getType().isArray()) {
          for (?? vals : aField) {
            System.out.println(vals);
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use something like this:

```
if (aField.getType().isArray()) {
  Object array = aField.get(obj);
  int length = Array.getLength(array);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Array.get(array, i));
  }
}
```

In other words, you first fetch the value from the field using `Field.get`, then use the `java.lang.reflect.Array` helper class to access the length and the individual elements.